# Nginx: Should I choose default or mydomain.conf configuration to serve a single domain in a server?

Tags: asp.net, nginx

I am new `Nginx`. Currently, I configured my domain to be served by `Nginx` on the `default` configuration as follows and it is working.

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Default configuration:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   uidcenterkl.my *.uidcenterkl.my;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

However, I learnt that I need to create domain specific directive such as `mywebiste.com.conf` as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/mywebiste.com.conf
```

**Question:**

What should I choose, `default` or `mywesbite.com.conf` to serve a single domain? And if I went with `mywebsite.com.conf`, how to deactivate `default` configuration so that it does not cause conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may actually not need to set up domain specific directive to serve a single domain. `default` directive should work fine for you.

And if you choose to use `mywesbite.com.conf`, all you need to do to disable `default` is to delete it from inside `sites-enabled` directory

After creating your `mywesbite.com.conf` feel free to delete the `default.conf` by running this command from your `sites-enabled` dirctory:

```
sudo rm ../sites-enabled/default.conf
```

Don't forget to restart your `nginx` after that command

```
systemctl restart nginx
```